# How to turn number from float into closest whole number php?

Tags: php

I have a form where I write a number and then I print other numbers until they reach an "x" number. So when I write 33.3 my output is 34.3, 35.3, 36.3 and etc. If my 'x' number is 100 the last printed number is 99.3 :/ So how can I make it my last printed number to be an int number? And how can I make my second number 34.3 to be 34? If is it possible write some examples :)

Comment: [RTM](http://php.net/manual/de/function.intval.php): `intval();`

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Please show your code. Otherwise this is very hard to understand. Please show any example code you have, and the expected input, and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
<?php

$number = 96.3;
$x = 100;

while ($number <= $x) {
    echo $number;
    if ($number != $x) {
        echo ', ';
    }
    $number = intval($number) + 1;
}
```

Output:

```
96.3, 97, 98, 99, 100
```

[`intval`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) will truncate the fractional part of the number and convert it to an integer. So you just add 1 to that number on each iteration of the loop until you reach x.

Comment: Thanx that 'intval' do the job :)